# Unable to approve a pending app request

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, administration, app-catalog

I want to add a SharePoint app inside our site, where from the SharePoint store i added the app, as follow:-
[image]

- then i received the following :-
  [image]
- after that i requested the app:-
  [image]
- but i am not sure how i can approve it >> i went to the app store, where i find the app request , but i am not sure how i can approve the app request:-
  [image]
- i edit the app >> select Approved from the status list , as follow:-
  [image]
- but still when i try to add the app i will get that it need to be approved, as follow:-

[image]

I am login using the office 365 admin and the office 365 admin does not have an email address..

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with the exact same app and reproduced this issue.

It seems that changing the **Status** from `Pending Permission` to `Approved` doesn’t actually approve the request.

---

Here is my test process:

I send a second request and click the link in the request Email and redirect to the **Approve or Reject App Request** page same as in this [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/request-app-installation-permissions#how-the-permission-request-flow-works) "Approve or deny requests" section.

[image]

The I click the **Approve** button on the page, it returns an error because there is a duplicated request item. The second request **Status** doesn’t get changed after submission, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

However, when I return to the SharePoint Store, I can see the message Your tenant administrator has to approve this app go away.

[image]

---

So my suggestion is, use a global admin account with a valid Exchange Online license to approve the request, directly from the email.